# JQuery problem using .delegate() function, trouble binding function to elements...

Tags: jquery, events, binding, delegates

I'm new to jquery and having a problem using .delegate() to bind a function to elements in my page.

I can't do this using .bind() because the DOM in the page changes when I partially reload part of the page.

I've looked at using .live() but it seems that this has been deprecated by .delegate().

I wondered if anyone might be able to help me as to where I might be going wrong?

I'm trying to build a tooltip that I can use throughout my site. I'm aware there are already libraries out jquery tools etc that have this functionality, but Id rather build a simple version myself.

Here's the code.

```
$jQuery.fn.myToolTip = function () {
    var offTopSide = 0;
    var offLeftSide = -360;

    $(this).mouseover(function () {
        //left side of button
        var currentLeftPosition = $(this).position().left;
        //top side of button
        var currentTopPosition = $(this).position().top;
        var myToolTip = $(this).next();
        myToolTip.css("top", (currentTopPosition + offTopSide) + "px");
        myToolTip.css("left", (currentLeftPosition + offLeftSide) + "px");
        myToolTip.show();
    });

    $(this).mouseout(function () {
        $(this).next().hide();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).delegate('a', "mouseover mouseout", function () {
        $(this).myToolTip();

    });
});
```

Heres the html...

```
<a class="button" href="">Mouse over this link...</a>
<div class="tooltip" style="display: none;">
    <div class="tooltip-inner">
        tooltip1
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
```

At the moment this seems to work ONLY after you mouseover and mouseout of the link ONCE. Mousing over on the second time triggers the tooltip..

Apologies if this is something really obvious.

Regards

S

Comment: Despite what you said, this is the kind of thing that is ***very*** difficult to get working properly, especially cross-browser, especially since these things tend to start small and simple, and then grow beyond the original scope. I really recommend you use qTip2 (or another well-tested plugin), since most mature libraries get wide exposure and are well tested. It wouldn't surprise me if in 6 months time relatively basic bugs are still plaguing you with this.

Comment: Also, there's almost no difference between delegating over the entire document and live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'm reading it, you are calling `myToolTip();` on the element on `mouseover` and `mouseout` in order to set the new `mouseover` & `mouseout` event callbacks so the second time you mouseover, the new event callbacks will get called.

you want to do this:

```
$(document).delegate('a', "mouseover", function (){
    //left side of button
    var currentLeftPosition = $(this).position().left;
    //top side of button
    var currentTopPosition = $(this).position().top;
    var myToolTip = $(this).next();
    myToolTip.css("top", (currentTopPosition + offTopSide) + "px");
    myToolTip.css("left", (currentLeftPosition + offLeftSide) + "px");
    myToolTip.show();
});
```

and this:

```
$(document).delegate('a', "mouseout", function () {
    $(this).next().hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mircea. This seems to work for me. Need to do a bit of cross browser testing. Cheers!